# Chrome Network Tab - What does Finish and Load metrics convey?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image: Chrome network tab Finish, DOMLoaded and Load metrics]

Here, the finish correctly shows the time it took to load the last JS widget on the webpage. I want to know what all metrics get added in the calculating Finish time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Finish` is calculated as `max timestamp` of all captured requests minus `start timestamp` ([source](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/network/NetworkLogView.js?q=maxTime+finish&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=443)):

```js
var nodes = this._nodesByRequestId.valuesArray();
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
    ...............................
    if (request.endTime > maxTime)
        maxTime = request.endTime;
}
.........................."Finish: %s", Number.secondsToString(maxTime - baseTime)));
```

As for `Load`, it [uses DOM `load`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/network/NetworkLogView.js?q=maxTime+finish&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=551) event time.

Comment: Does Finish corresponds to window.load() response time? On our web page a third party JS widget rendering is taking around 5-7 sec and Finish response time is coinciding with this delay, hence wanted to understand if it window.load() event which is blocked till the widget is completely loaded.

Comment: `Finish` changes dynamically with each new request. It's always the maximum time. Of course, in case there were no more requests after document's load event, it coincides with `load` time.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! One more question - On Chrome network tab can we get the window.load() time value?

Comment: Well, it's the `Load` time. Or do you mean programmatically? I think there are many known ways, I just didn't use any myself.

Comment: Though load time is not taking into account the JS widget rendering time. I want to exclusively calculate the delay the widget rendering is taking.

Comment: Why `though`? I don't see any contradictions. Page load time is calculated based on window load event. `Finish` is just the latest request's time which may happen even an hour after page was loaded.

Comment: Yes it seems the way you suggest and I did tried verifying the same for different requests using network tab. I will research more on how to calculate the 6-7 sec delay we are noticing in the application.